# match the given date taken from user with current date

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, datetime

i am working on a project where i need to match the given date(taken from user) with today and i need to run the code only the date is greater than today i tried various ways but it is reflecting some conversion errors and i used below code where i am getting the same output as false even if i enter the days previous to today and also after today ..  i think i gone wrong through the conversion i think . i think i am comparing the two strings . but i cant get the expected output for the same even if i tried various ways . please help me to solve the problem here is the sample code that i tired in my project

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today().strftime('%d-%m-%y')
examdate=input('enter date in dd-mm-yy')
print(examdate>today)
```

input and outputs (current date is 30-06-18)

enter date in dd-mm-yy29-06-18
False

enter date in dd-mm-yy29-06-18
False

enter date in dd-mm-yy06-06-96
False

enter date in dd-mm-yy20-05-20
False

Comment: please add possible input,output you are expecting and output you got.

Comment: i edited the question check once now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your code is comparing strings rather than date objects
so try and understand comparing date objects

```
from datetime import datetime
examdate=str(input('enter date in dd-mm-yy'))
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(examdate,'%d-%m-%y')
today = datetime.now()

print today.strftime('%d-%m-%y')
if datetime_object>today:
  print("Do Somthing")
```